# Running an external (C++) program with a parameter file

Tags: external-calls

I want to run an external piece of code, which takes in a parameter file. It's structured like:

```
param1 1.0
param2 0.0
param3 2.0
param4 0.5
```

I want to execute the program with parameter files which vary some parameter in some range. What is the best way to generate such parameter file.

Solution by Henrik Schumacher:

```
Export["a.txt", 
 StringJoin[
  "param1 1
  param2 1.0
  param3 ", ToString[param3],"
  param4 1"],
"Text"]
```

Comment: Is this about Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: Yes, i am using the output of the program in mathematica.

Comment: Have a look for `Run` and `RunThrough`. `Import["! <command>", "Text"]`  also works.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher i am currently using Run to execute it, but i need to execute it with various parameter files, which i need to generate. Which command would be suited to do that?

Comment: You can generate parameter files with `Export`. E.g. `Export[a.txt,<string>,"Text"]`. And you can use `ToString` and `StringJoin` to generat e the string from Mathematica expressions.